# retrieve url parameter and populate a hidden form field

Tags: forms, url, parameters

I have a simple form and I want to pull a url parameter and populate one of the hidden fields with that value.

for example the url is www.myurltest.html?placement=xyz

here is my form code with js.  when I load the page, the value xyz is not being filled into the hidden field.  The way I am checking is after page refresh, I check the source to see if the value is in the html.  Please let me know what is wrong, I'm also not a developer by trade so this is extra challenging.

```
 <script>
 function getParameterByName(name)
 {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(results == null)
     return "";
  else
 return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
 }
 </script>
<form method="post" action="http://xyz.com" >

<ul><li ><label>First Name:</label><input name="firstName" id="firstName" type='text'     value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='1' ></li>

<li ><label>Last Name:</label><input name="lastName" id="lastName" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='2' /></li>

<li  ><label>Email:</label><input name="email" id="email" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='3' /></li>

<li ><label>Company Name:</label><input name="name" id="name" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='4' /></li>
<li>
<input type='submit' foo=en_US value='testtest' name='submit' />
</li>  
</ul>

<input type="hidden" name="placement" id="placement" value=""  />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("placement").value = getParameterByName("placement");
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value won't appear in the source. If you use Chrome F12 dev tools, you can inspect the value instead. It seems to be working for me.

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function getParameterByName(name)
                 {
                  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
                  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
                  if(results == null)
                     return "";
                  else
                 return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
                 }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="http://xyz.com" >
            <ul>
                <li><label>First Name:</label><input name="firstName" id="firstName" type='text'     value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='1' ></li>
                <li><label>Last Name:</label><input name="lastName" id="lastName" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='2' /></li>
                <li><label>Email:</label><input name="email" id="email" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='3' /></li>
                <li><label>Company Name:</label><input name="name" id="name" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='4' /></li>
                <li><input type='submit' foo=en_US value='testtest' name='submit' /></li>
            </ul>
            <input type="hidden" name="placement" id="placement" value=""  />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById("placement").value = getParameterByName("placement");
            </script>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified but it is in a script tag I did not copy paste correctly